# psql copy to csv

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

in postgresql when running like this I get successful result...

```
\copy (select * from user) To 'test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV Header;
```

but when I run like this it fails...

```
\copy
(select * from user)
To 'test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV Header;

LINE 2: To 'test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV Header;
```

can someone suggest how to execute with second pattern...

Answer (score 0):

`psql` (the PostgreSQL command line client) commands are preceded with a backslash and terminated by return, not a semicolon. A semicolon terminates SQL commands, but `\COPY` is not SQL command. `COPY` without a leading backslash would be a SQL command. `psql` commands are written on a single line.

`psql` commands are run in your client machine, while SQL commands are run in the server. If you connected to a remote server, `\COPY` would use a csv file on your client filesystem and `COPY` a file on server filesystem.