# Imoprting a csv file to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import a csv file into a postgres database. The csv file is on a local server while the db is on another server. From what I've seen, the recommendations were using \copy.

```
     \COPY tablename from '/path/to/local/file.csv' with csv
```

But it shows me a syntax error. And the problem is at \copy.
Any suggestion how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that? `\copy` is a [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) command and as such it only works in `psql`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319975/psql-copy-to-csv

Comment: I get it, is there any other way how to import a csv file into postgres, from a local server?

Comment: Yes, there is. What client program are you using to connect to database? Like, is is psql? Are you calling 'local server' the machine you run psql on? Then do it the way in my link. Otherwise, please explain what in your setup is different.

Comment: no, actually, I'm using that statement in a jdbc program, so I am not able to run psql, I think.